# Angularjs - after I enter a value into a <intput> field with ng-model the value changes to undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a simple form that accepts an input. For some reason when I change the value the scope variable changes to undefined.

```
<body ng-controller="myctrler">
<input ng-model="t.unsubscribeEmail" type="email" class="textboxfields" placeholder="Enter email address">
</body>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.k=
{
    unsubscribeEmail : "not"
};
```

The value before I enter anything into the inputbox is "not". As soon as I type something in the input the value changes to undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: The value is invalid (not an email adress), so the model is `undefined`. Try `not@example.com` to see the difference.

Comment: Crap, i guess its too early for me. I wasn't thinking about the validation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input type text or write valide email

```
<input ng-model="t.unsubscribeEmail" type="text" class="textboxfields" placeholder="Enter email address">
```

or write valide email in

```
<input ng-model="t.unsubscribeEmail" type="email" class="textboxfields" placeholder="Enter email address">
```