# AJAX page not meeting success criteria...Error in JSON return type....Always showing "There is an error" no matter what

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

**Hi guys. I created an AJAX page that validates a form and displays errors.But the problem is no matter what it always displays there is an error **

**Contact form:**

```
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name" class="fullname">
        <span>Full name:</span>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
    </label>
    <label for="email" class="email">
      <span>Email:</span>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </label>
    <label for="name1" class="message">
      <span>Message:</span> 
      <textarea name="name1" id="name1"></textarea>
    </label>
    <div class="btns">
        <a class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').reset()">Clear</a>
        <a class="button" name="submit" id="submit">Send</a>                                                
    </div>            
</form>
```

**The AJAX program that I wrote is**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $('#submit').click(function() {  
            $('#contact-form').hide(0);
            $('#message').hide(0);              
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'post.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data: {
                    email : $('#email').val(),
                    name1 : $('#name1').val(),
                    name  : $('#fullname').val()
                },
                success : function(data){
                    $('#waiting').hide(500);
                    $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                        .text(data.msg).show(500);
                    if (data.error === true)
                        $('#contact-form').show(500);
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#waiting').hide(500);
                    $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                    $('#contact-form').show(500);
                }
            });             
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

**And Lastly the PHP Code for Validation is**

```
<?php
    $return['error'] = false;        
    while (true) {
        if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';
            break;
        }        
        if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you name.';
            break;
        }        
        if (empty($_POST['name1'])) {
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you message.';
            break;
        }        
        break;
    }        
    if (!$return['error'])
        $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $_POST['email'] . ' as email, ' . $_POST['name'] . ' as name and ' . $_POST['email'] . ' as url.';
     echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

**It would be great help if extra validators for email check and length check are added.Thanks a LOT in advance.**

Comment: Your error method has 3 parameters. Use a `console.log` on them and see what the error it.

Comment: I am sorry but can you please explain in detail.

Comment: use `console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)` in `error:function(){...}` and open the browser console to see the errors (usually pressing F12)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sid/Desktop/GLENSE%20Work/GLENSE%20website/post.php. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest {statusText: "", status: 0, responseURL: "", response: "", responseType: ""…} "parsererror" undefined

Comment: Seems like you're not running on a server. Your request is being blocked for security reasons. You may either try with Mozilla Firefox or install a local web server if you want to use ajax. Like this you can test it in a good old fashioned way by posting the form to a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input type text or write valide email

```
  <input ng-model="t.unsubscribeEmail" type="text" class="textboxfields" placeholder="Enter email address">
```

or write valide email in

```
   <input ng-model="t.unsubscribeEmail" type="email" class="textboxfields" placeholder="Enter email address">
```

[use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324666/angularjs-after-i-enter-a-value-into-a-intput-field-with-ng-model-the-value/26324769#26324769)

Comment: Hey it works but the vaildation is not being done.When i executed the file it shows the following output

You've entered: undefined as email, undefined as name and undefined as url.

Comment: The data from the form is not going to the php.Even when i fill in the details it shows You've entered: undefined as email, undefined as name and undefined as url

Comment: yes when i filled in the input fields it shd display what i entered but its showing null.

Comment: Change input type text or write valide emaile for sendet value

Comment: Still the same.I changed input type="text" but no help